# javascript repeat action

Tags: javascript, jquery

how to do a same loop action? thank you.

```
$('a.level').click(function() {
var level   = $(this).parent('li').attr("class");
var nxvl    = parseInt(level)+1;
var dir     = $(this).html();

var curr    = $(this);

var data = new Object();
    data.n      = new Date().getTime();
    data.act    = "getdirectory";
    data.level  = level;
    data.direct = dir;

var str = $.toJSON(data); 
$.post('ajax.php', { str: str }, function(result){
    var data = eval('('+obj.data+')');
    var html = [];
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
        html[key] = "<li class='"+nxvl+"'><a href='javascript:void(0);' title='' class='level'>"+eval(value)+"</a><ul></ul></li>";
    });

    $(curr).next('ul').html(html.join(""));
    $('a.level').click(function() {

        // do the same action
    }

});
return(false);
```

});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you probably want to use live handlers.  Change your outer:

```
$('a.level').click(function() {
  ...
}
```

To:

```
$('a.level').live('click', function() {
  ...
}
```

Then you don't worry about adding new click handlers after you've updated the HTML in `$(curr).next('ul').html(...)`

Comment: This will only work if the newly created elements match the original selector exactly. It will work for the original question, but it's good to remember.

Answer (score 0):

Try moving the function logic out of the anonymous function and into a named function.

So instead of:

```
$('element').click(function(){ /* logic */ });
```

You would have:

```
function myFunc() { /* logic */ }
$('element').click(myFunc);
```

That way, within the function you can call the function again, or in your case, attach it to another element you have just created.